# Android: Handling KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT interrupt music playback

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

Title: Handling KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT interrupt music playback

In my android app i want to handle the next key from my bluetooth speaker in an own way. When pressing the key i want to raise/lower the volume. But every time i press the hardware key i get an interruption. The interruption is about a half of a second. The
app receives the broadcast after the interruption (not before). The speaker is the "EasyAcc Mini 2 Portabler 4.1 Bluetooth" Speaker.

The following code snippets show the implementation:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver android:name=".services.player.BluetoothMediaReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999999999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

registering the bluetooth receiver:

```
  AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  Intent i = new Intent(activity, BluetoothMediaReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 1, i, 0);
  audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(pi);
```

BluetoothMediaReceiver is a Broadcast receiver

and finally the receive method:

```
  protected void processReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    KeyEvent key = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (key.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      if (key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT) {
        volumeChanger.volumeUp();
      }
      else if (key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS) {
        volumeChanger.volumeDown();
      }
    }
    abortBroadcast();
  }
```

When creating a breakpoint in the processReceive method, the breakpoint is hit after the music interruption.

I use the MediaPlayer to play the music from an mp3 file. While i hear no music, the player continues playing (does not pause).

Can anybody give me a hint to avoid the interruption.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the problem was the Bluetooth speaker.

I tested it with another bluetooth headphone and there were no interruptions.